# Best way to store results data in database?

Tags: database, database-design

I have results data like this:

```
1. account, name, #, etc
2. account, name, #, etc
...
10. account, name, #, etc
```

I have approximately 1 set of results data generated each week.

Currently it's stored like so:

```
DATETIME  DATA_BLOB
```

Which is annoying because I can't query any of the data without parsing the BLOB into a custom object. I'm thinking of changing this.

I'm thinking of having one giant table:

```
DATETIME   RANK   ACCOUNT    NAME   NUMBER  ... ETC
  date1      1     user1      nn      #
  date1      2     user2      nn      #
  ...
  date1      10    userN      nn      #
  date2      1     user5      nn      #
  date2      2     user12     nn      #
  ...
  date2      10    userX      nn      #
```

I don't know anything about database design principles, so can someone give me feedback on whether this is a good approach or there might be a better one?

Thanks

Comment: This is a perfectly valid design, provided that all the rows are guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is ok to have a table like that, if there are not *one-to-many* relationships. In that case, it would be more efficient to have multiple tables like in my example below. Here are some general tips as well:

**Tip: Good practice** My professor told me that it's always good to have an "ID" column, which is a unique number identifier for each item in the table (1, 2, 3… etc.).  (Perhaps that was the intent of your "Number" column.)  I think SQLite forces each table to have an ID column anyways.

**Tip: Saving storage space** - Also, if there is a *one-to-many* relationship (example: one name has many accounts) then it might save space to have a separate table for the accounts, and then store the ID of the name in the first table- so that way you are storing many ints instead of duplicate strings.

**Tip: Efficiency** - Some databases have specific frameworks designed to handle relationships such as *many-to-one* or *many-to-many*, so if you use their framework for that (I don't remember exactly how to do it) it will probably work more efficiently.

**Tip: Saving storage space** - If you make your own ID column it might be a waste if it automatically includes an "ID" column anyways - so you might want to check for that possibility.

***Conceptual Example:  (Storing multiple accounts for the same name)***

**Poor Solution**:
Storing everything in 1 table (inefficient, because it duplicates Bob's name, rank, and datetime):

```
ID  NAME  RANK  DATETIME  ACCOUNT

1   Bob    1      date1      bob_account_1

2   Joe    2      date2      user2_joe

3   Bob    1      date1      bob_account_2

4   Bob    1      date1      bobs_third_account
```

**Better Solution:** Having 2 tables to prevent duplicated information (Also demonstrates the usefulness of ID's). I named the 2 tables "Account" and "Name."

**Table 1: "Account"**  (Note that NAME_ID refers to the ID column of Table 2)

```
ID    NAME_ID  ACCOUNT  

1       1     bob_account_1

2       2     user2_joe

3       1     bob_account_2

4       1     bobs_third_account
```

**Table 2: "Name"**

```
ID  NAME  RANK  DATETIME 

1   Bob    1      date1      

2   Joe    2      date2
```

I'm not a database expert so this is just some of what I learned in my internet programming class. I hope this helps lead you in the right direction in further research.

Comment: Thanks.... This has led me to read some tutorials on database design and I'll be painfully redesigning mine to remove the redundancy between tables and present data in a more easily queried fashion.